# visual studio 2017 cordova vstac failed - The operation has timed out

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build `cordova` app for ios in `visual studio 2017` with `macincloud` `xcode 8.3` and `ios 10.2`.

I have been getting this vstac failed error. I have uninstalled professional and installed enterprise. error still the same. raised a ticket in the vs developer community but said that fixes are released for this error. but no use.

can somebody throw some light here ...

What I figured out after one by one copy pasting the solution contents from solution to solution and building for hour together that,

build is throwing out due to size of the solution.

**Is there any max limit or time limit or some thing which I should mention somewhere to handle this "time out error"?**

error text

```
1>Done building target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in project "appname.jsproj".
1>Target "BuildMDA" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets":
1>  Task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(Platform)' == 'android' AND '$(TelemetryEnabled)' == 'True' ) was evaluated as ( 'iOS' == 'android' AND 'True' == 'True' ).
1>  Task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" skipped, due to false condition; ( '@(BuildMDACpuSpecificPlatform)' != '' AND '$(TelemetryEnabled)' == 'True') was evaluated as ( '' != '' AND 'True' == 'True').
1>  Task "VsTac" skipped, due to false condition; ( '@(BuildMDACpuSpecificPlatform)' != '' ) was evaluated as ( '' != '' ).
1>  Using "VsTac" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>  Task "VsTac"
1>    Task Parameter:Platform=iOS
1>    Task Parameter:Configuration=Release
1>    Task Parameter:ProjectName=appname
1>    Task Parameter:BuildServerUrl=https://223.25.233.119:3000/cordova
1>    Task Parameter:CertificateName=223-25-233-119.revdns.8toinfinity.com.sg.RB
1>    Task Parameter:DebugTarget=iOSRemoteDevice
1>    Task Parameter:DetectNpmProxy=True
1>    Task Parameter:InstanceId=f6bbadf6
    ------ Submitting new build request to: https://223.25.233.119:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=7.0.1&cfg=release&options=--device
1>    MSBUILD : cordova-build error : An error occurred uploading to the build server https://223.25.233.119:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=7.0.1&cfg=release&options=--device: The operation has timed out
    ------ 05/24/2017 22:51:45 Checking on build status from  [Attempt 1]
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: The "VsTac" task failed unexpectedly.
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: Parameter name: requestUriString
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.CreateWebRequest(String url)
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.PollForBuildComplete(String buildingUrl, Int32 interval, Int32 attempts)
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.Build()
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.BuildPlatform()
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.Execute()
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>  Done executing task "VsTac" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "appname.jsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Done building project "appname.jsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Project Performance Summary:
1>    115494 ms  D:\appname ios\appname\appname\appname.jsproj   1 calls
1>
1>Target Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  AfterBuild                                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeBuild                                1 calls
1>        0 ms  CheckForIPACancel                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  CoreBuild                                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   1 calls
1>        0 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          1 calls
1>        1 ms  EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion   1 calls
1>        1 ms  CompileTypeScript                          1 calls
1>        1 ms  PreComputeCompileTypeScript                1 calls
1>    115486 ms  BuildMDA                                   1 calls
1>
1>Task Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  Message                                    2 calls
1>        1 ms  MdaVerifySetup                             1 calls
1>        3 ms  VsTsc                                      2 calls
1>    115485 ms  VsTac                                      1 calls
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:01:55.49
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vstac error I was getting because of network latency which I had to figure out creating a empty solution and then putting one by one object of my solution code into it to test which part of the code is "either failing at build". no code was failing but VSTAC failure was there due to large image sizes in screens and large number of files.

this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your platform folder and run it again. It works for me for a while, but it is not a final solution.
I also increased timeout on /users/{{your user}}/.taco_home/remote_builds/RemoteBuild.Config

I also updated remotebuild: npm install -g remotebuild

This solution doesn't work with release build.

UPDATED: Jun, 07, 2017: I changed for a wired connection and everything works perfectly.